# Number of solutions to equation $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i = R$ where $x_i>k$ where $k$ is a positive number

Tags: combinatorics

I know that the number of solutions to an equation of the form:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i = R$$

equals $\binom{n+R-1}{R}$.

I am aware of the $x_i$ LESS THAN EQUAL TO case where, if say $x_6 \leq 3$, I would subtract $3$ from $R$; i.e., $R=R-3$ and find $\binom{n+R-1}{R}$.

However, I came a across a problem where $n=6$ and  **$x_6$ has to NO MORE than 3; i.e., $x_6 <3$.**

What do I do in this case? Do I simply add it because it seems like the inverse of the previous one. Thanks in advance and sorry for the poor formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the post correctly, you want $x_6$ to be no more than $3$, while the other $x_i$ are non-negative integers.

So $x_6$ is $0$, $1$, $2$, or $3$.  We find the number of solutions in each of these cases and add up.

So for $x_6=0$ we are finding the number of solutions of $x_1+\cdots +x_5=R$.

For $x_6=1$ we are finding the number of solutions of $x_1+\cdots +x_5=R-1$.

And so on. You know how to solve these $4$ subproblems.

**Another way:** We can save some time as follows. We know how many solutions there are with no restriction apart from $x_i$ non-negative integers. Now we count the **bad** distributions, where $x_6\ge 4$.

To count this, give $4$ candies to Kid $6$. Then distribute the remaining $R-4$ candies among the $6$ kids, with no restriction.

That gives the answer $\binom{6+R-1}{R}-\binom{6+R-4-1}{R-4}$.

Comment: Aah i had thought of this but I thought we would be overcounting. Why won't we?

Comment: Also, on a slightly related note....When do we use (n+R-1) C (R) and when do we use (n+R-1) C (R-1)

Comment: The possibilities have been divided into $4$ groups. Any two of these groups are *disjoint* (have no outcomes in common). So if we add up we will not be double-counting.

Comment: I see. The second query?

Comment: If we are finding the number of non-negative integer solutions of $x_1+\cdots+x_n=S$, we use $\binom{n+S-1}{S}$, which is exactly the same as $\binom{n+S-1}{n-1}$.  (I prefer the second form, and it looks as if you prefer the first.) So as long as you know how many candies $S$ you are dividing, and how many kids $n$ are the recipients, the formula to use should be clear.